# LCM of n positive integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory

Let $a_1,a_2, \cdots ,a_n$ be $n$ positive integers and let $L=LCM(a_1,a_2, \cdots ,a_n)$. For $a_i$'s consecutive integers a non trivial lower bound as well as an upper bound are known.(Farhi and co). For arbitrary $a_i$'s are there any known results for a LB or an UB for $L$ ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have just arbitrary integers and do not know of any special properties you may have:

1. Distict prime numbers, hence $L$ become the product of all of them.
2. One of the numbers $a_i$ being the least common multiple of the others, where hence $a_i = L$.

In general, each number is a lower bound for L and the product is an upper bound, and if you dont know anything more, then these two examples show that you cant say anything more.